# Regexp for matching closing braces

Tags: python, regex, latex

I have a latex file which might have this kind of code inside

```
\MyTitle{This is a title with some \commands{with some arguments} inside}
which is followed by some text 
with many lines and any kind of things inside
and at some point an abstract can be defined like
\MyAbstract{%
including the abstract which can have also \commands{inside with possiblguments} or not and can longer than a line
```

what I am trying to do is to write some python code which finds the title and abstract within the file. What I did and was working is to read the file as a string and use the following code for the title

```
abstract = re.search("\\\MyAbstract{(.*?)}", alltext).groups()[0]
title = re.search(r"\\MyTitle{(.*?)}", alltext).groups()[0]
```

This worked fine until I found a title or abstract with other curly braces inside which makes the ungreedy regexp to fail. If I remove the ungreedy symbol then it will match much more text since it is all in one line and I would want to match from the origin curly brace until the one which closes it.

What would be the best way of doing this? Since the abstract can span several lines and the title is usually one line I am not sure what would be the best way of doing this.

I have searched for this but couldn't find a working solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Nested brackets are a canonical example of what regular expressions cannot handle. You need the power of context-free grammars/languages to parse them correctly.

Comment: PyPi regex can deal with nested parentheses. However, isn't there any good library to parse these files?

Comment: To match this with a regular expression, you would need recursion, which is not supported by standard python

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I thought that since I am kind of new with regexps thre might something I was missing. I will take a look and if anything else fails I will write my own function for this which might not be efficient but for what I want should be enough :)

Comment: Summarizing in parts what others have written, 1.) technically speaking, most re engines today can recognize context-free languages ("patterns") which usually suffices for structure-aware (eg. brackets, tags) matching, and 2.) you'd usually get along with strictly regular patterns (ie. less powerful re  engines) if you assume a maximum depth for nesting structures, which may origin from independent considerations - like an xml schema or whether searched content is machine-generated vs. authored by humans 3.) this reasoning does not matter much in practice as ...

Comment: ... much less complicated re patterns quickly prove to become an unmaintainable mess even to their author. Its often much better to use a full-fledged parser ( eg. xml ) or a very simple re ( eg. keyword matching ) + ordinary coding to check the context of the match sites.

Answer (score 3):

If the nesting of the mustaches is only 1 level, then this regex should be close to what you want.

```
\\(My\w+)[{]((?:[^{}]*|[{][^{}]*[}])*)[}]
```

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/G2bZGO/3)

If this were not the Python re module, but a regex engine that supports recursion
(like PCRE or [PyPi regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/)), then a regex like this could work:

```
[\\](My\w+)([{](?>[^{}]+|(?2))*[}])
```

Comment: With PyPi regex, `regex.search(r"[\\](My\w+)([{](?>[^{}]+|(?2))*[}])", s).group(0)` returns `\MyTitle{This is a title with some \commands{with some arguments} inside}`. So, the second one does not really only require PCRE.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Oh I see, so the default re module doesn't support it, but PyPi brings more regex to the table.  Thanks for the insight.